# Python datetime clock function stuck

Tags: python

I'm making a program for school and decided that I wanted to add the date and time to my menu which appears at the beginning of the program.

I do not know if it is just something small that I have not seen but this is my code:

```
def menu():

    print('                      Please pick an option:'
      '\n                       *******************'
      '\n                       1. Add Events'
      '\n                       2. Display Events'
      '\n                       3. Add students to Event'
      '\n                       4. Store winners of Events'
      '\n                       5. House Points'
      '\n                       6. Exit')




    option = int(input('\n\n\nOption:')) #ask user to input integer
    os.system('cls')

    if option == 1:
        opt_1()

    elif option == 2:
        opt_2()

    elif option == 3:
        opt_3()

    elif option == 4:
        opt_4()

    elif option == 5:
        opt_5()

    elif option == 6:
        os.system('cls')
        print('The program will now terminate...')
        time.sleep(1)
        exit() #exit program

    else:
        exit()



def clock_and_date():

    while True:
        now = datetime.now()

        print('%s/%s/%s          %s:%s:%s' % (now.day,now.month,now.year,now.hour,now.minute,now.second))

        time.sleep(1)
        os.system('cls')
        sys.stdout.flush()           


menu()
```

I haven't called the function clock_and_date yet, but I want it to appear at the top of the terminal where I have left space in the print of the menu. 
However, if I call the clock_and_date function at the top of the menu function then it just shows that and not the menu.

Comment: as an aside, `datetime.datetime` has an in-built `strftime` method that will format dates for you. This would be `print(now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y            %H:%M:%S"))`. The relevant formatting is in the docs, but has a handy quick reference at [strftime.org](http://www.strftime.org)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to programming -- it's not that easy!

The problem is the `while True` loop inside your function, as you may have guessed. Once you enter that loop, you're never coming out again. Getting part of your code to run while the rest of your program waits for user input is one of the first hurdles to effective UI programming, but unfortunately it's QUITE DIFFICULT to do this in a terminal window.

I'd abandon this idea for now. It's not impossible (if you're on the right platform, in the right terminal) but it's certainly much harder and much less "batteries included" than most of Python is.

Comment: Thank you! You are very kind. I am quite new to programming. So is there no way that I can make a clock? I do have a pop up GUI at the beginning of my program. If there is no possible way then thank you anyway for your time, kind sir.

Comment: @NimRod surely it's possible, but I strongly recommend against it if only because it's quite a bit of added complexity for what's essentially fluff. You can cut almost 100% of that complexity by making your clock not run in realtime, but only update when you print the menu again. Try that, instead!

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a way to do this without using UI. You might want to look into multi-threading or multiprocessing. This lets you run two different bits of code at once. You could have an infinite loop updating the time and have the main program run separate from this. Here is a basic example:

```
from threading import thread

def func1():
while True:
    print("Hello")

def func2():
    while True:
        print("Bye")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target = func1).start()
    Thread(target = func2).start()
```

You can use your own functions to update a variable of the time and then display it in the main function wherever you want it. I hope this helps.